# Using ReadFile to read entire PhysicalDrive contents

Tags: c, winapi

I am fairly new to C, and I am trying to write a small application that will read the entire raw contents of a drive.

Here is my code;

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    char buff[512];

    hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("%d",GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    SetFilePointer(hFile, 512*0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(hFile, buff, 512, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I put the ReadFile into a loop to read all the data on the drive? I eventually need to save the contents of the buffer to the disk.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the return value from `ReadFile`. "If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero (TRUE). If the function fails, or is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (FALSE). To get extended error information, call the GetLastError function."

Comment: You can only do this if there are no volumes with mounted filesystems on the drive.  Blocks occupied by filesystems can't be accessed via the `PhysicalDrive` device on modern versions of Windows.  Even with administrator access.

Comment: @BenVoigt Just to clarify, reading by administrator is not restricted anywhere. Writing to areas claimed by mounted volumes is blocked on NT6.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Ahh, ok.  Here's the doc http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/942448

Answer (score 2):

The loop might look like this:

```
hFile = CreateFile(...);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // handle error
}

while (true)
{
    unsigned char buff[32768]; // needs to be a multiple of sector size
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    if (!ReadFile(hFile, buff, sizeof buff, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
        // handle error
    }
    if (dwBytesRead == 0)
    {
        break; // we reached the end
    }
    // do something with the dwBytesRead that were read
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
```